# Which crosspath is better overall for a 4-0-0 alch

Tags: bloons-td-6

So, a bit of backstory: I've been using 4-2-0 alchs for buffing because when you get perishing potions, it buffs brews and stims, but every YouTuber I've seen uses 4-0-2 alchs for buffing because it throws them out more often. so I've been wondering if one is better. 4-2-0 is quality over quantity and 4-0-2 is quantity over quality, so which is generally better?

by the way, perishing is better for 5-0-0 alchs because the buffs are permanent so why would you need to throw them faster if the potions are permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I play BTD6, and here is the pros of both and which I would pick.

- 4-0-2
  Faster throws (faster buffing in an area)
- 4-2-0
  funny number
  Buff boost (better buffing)

For me, if I needed DPS I would use 4-2-0 alchs, and if I need to cover a to of units I would use 4-0-2 alchs.

Comment: ah yes funny number hahaha

Comment: Well, I watch Tewity's videos and it seems he always uses 4-2-0.